# Increase and decreasing screen brightness crashes Minecraft

Tags: 14.04, java, minecraft

**Problem:**

When increasing or decreasing the screen brightness, Minecraft crashes and to an extent freezes my computer UI. What I mean by to an extent is that I can move the cursor around, but I can't click on anything. I can also run keyboard shortcuts and  type, which is how I restore my system by terminating all java processes with pkill.

[Paste link to error log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10981428/)

What causes minecraft to crash and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. I figured that Minecraft was running via the Intel integrated graphics card. I used optirun to fire up Minecraft and my issue was solved.